# Is there a way to use @mixin within a @function in SASS/SCSS?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is there a way to use mixin inside a function with `@include`?

I tried and got `Error: This at-rule is not allowed here.`.

It is simply a debug function that checks the type of the arguments.

Comment: Can you include the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The Sass documentation states that the [`@function`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) at-rule

> ...can only contain [universal statements](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/structure#universal-statements), as well as the @return at-rule which indicates the value to use as the result of the function call.

An `@include` at-rule isn't a universal statement.

Comment: This might seem like an obvious question, but does universal statement also exclude built-in modules (i.e. `sass:map`)?

Comment: I'm not sure. Please refer to the documentation or post another question on SO.